# Typecasting (underflow?) differences intel vs M1

Tags: c++, macos, apple-m1

When running the following program:

```
double temp;
double blue1 = 200;
double blue2 = 300;
double blue = blue1 - blue2;
std::cout << blue << std::endl;
temp = (unsigned char) blue;
std::cout << temp << std::endl;
```

I get 0 on my M1 machine and random number on my intel machine. Same compiler, and I am compiling from the command line. What is this about?

I was not expecting to see a 0 in the tem value.

Comment: @George You are correct about the UB but this isn't a strict aliasing issues, just a floating point to integer conversion issue.

Comment: `-100.0` is not in the range of `0` .. `255` (presuming an 8-bit char), so it's **undefined behavior**.

Comment: I wonder why you wouldn't expect a `0`, but would expect some random value.

Comment: I had some code for image manipulation and we had clamped the values in the past to account for the undefined behavior. This was not needed in the new machine. That is all.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has undefined behavior, so all results are correct.  `temp = (unsigned char) blue;` does a Floating-integral conversion and per [[conv.fpint]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv.fpint#1)

> A prvalue of a floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. **The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type.**

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

The behavior is undefined if the floating point value is outside the range of the integer type you are converting to.